# Get records belonging to other records

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get records belonging to other records. Here's a breakdown of the problem.

I have the following article records and would like to get the users who have articles with the status (0):

```
$articles = Article::whereStatus(0)->get();
```

The Article model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Article extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'title', 'content', 'status'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

I understand I can iterate through the articles records then fetch the respective user records but might this be inefficient? i.e.

```
foreach($articles as $article)
{
    $user = User::find($article->user_id);  
}
```

Is there an alternative method to get those users records with the articles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this from the inverse direction:

```
User::whereHas('articles', fn ($q) => $q->whereStatus(0))->get();
```

Get all users that have any articles where status is 0.

You just need to have the `articles` relationship setup on `User`.

If you want all those User models to also have their `articles` relationship loaded with only Articles where status is 0, you can do a constrained eager load:

```
User::whereHas('articles', $filter = fn ($q) => $q->whereStatus(0))
    ->with('articles', $filter)
    ->get();
```

If you are starting with `$articles` you can lazy eager load the `user` relationship then pluck them from the Collection:

```
$articles->load('user')->pluck('user')->unique()
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) `whereHas`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Constraining Eager Loads](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#constraining-eager-loads) `with`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-load) `load`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-collections#method-unique) `unique`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) `pluck`

Answer (score 0):

```
$articles = Article::with('user')->whereStatus(0)->get();
```

Try lazy load the relation. Please refer the link below for more information.

[eloquent-relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading)